# Us v. We in parenthetical commas

Tags: clauses

Which of the following is correct?

> "If you, like **us**, were altered  by the experience..."

or

> "if you, like **we**, were altered by the experience..."

I would tend to go with "we" since it matches with the verb that follows it.

I would love to find a reference in the Chicago Manual of Style, but have not spotted it yet.

Comment: If a person is going to nit-pick here, perhaps they are better starting by asking whether 'like' should be 'as'. ' ... like we ...' may show signs of logical conformity, but sounds ridiculously highbrow in most contexts. The objective is replacing the subjective in many such roles nowadays (It's me! / That's him now. / A man like him ...), and I'd certainly avoid 'we' in your example. If you don't like the other version, rephrase: "If you were altered by the experience – as we were – ..."

Answer (score 1):

In the phrase 'like us', *like* is a preposition, and takes the accusative case. But in phrases such as 'like we do' or 'like they are', *like* is a conjunction, and the phrase has a subject in the nominative case. For instance,

> If you, like us, were altered by the experience...

but

> If you were altered by the experience, like we were,...

See [this link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/like) at the Oxford Dictionaries website for more info.